# PL/SQL equivalent of SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What would be the PL/SQL equivalent of this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table(OWNER.PACKAGE.get_exam('123456789'));
```

This is the Function that I am trying to call:

```
FUNCTION get_exam(id IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN ab_assign_v1
    IS
        CURSOR c_exams(cid VARCHAR2) IS
        SELECT t_api_exam_v1(
                sei.person_id, --unique id
                l.description --loc description
            )
            FROM my_view sei
            JOIN loc l
            ON sei.loc_code = l.loc_code
        v_collection ab_assign_v1;
    BEGIN
        OPEN c_exams(id);
        FETCH c_exams BULK COLLECT INTO v_collection;
        CLOSE c_exams;
        RETURN v_collection;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            error_a1.raise_error(SQLCODE, SQLERRM);
    END get_exam;
```

Comment: what is the return type of the function?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp it's a collection

Comment: In light of your comments below, you'll need to post the definition of your function in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to return the result of a function :

```
  select owner.package.get_exam('123456789') from table
```

Comment: It's giving me: PL/SQL: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Comment: did you try package.function ?

Comment: hope the function already exists in the package and you are calling the right function with right values ?

Comment: Yes the function is returning correct values when I call it using regular SQL, but getting this error when using PL/SQL

Comment: However, for a PL/SQL function to be called in SQL (SELECT, INSERT, etc), it must be free from certain side effects (ie. it can't modify certain kinds of state within the database). To be called as a column in a SELECT, it must not modify the database (insert or update, for example), perform DDL, or commit a transaction.can you explain what that function returns

Comment: The function isn't making any changes to the state of DB. It's only running a SELECT query returning a result set with 11 columns of data

Comment: DECLARE
   v_sql VARCHAR2(255);
   v_return VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
      v_return := OWNER.PACKAGE.FUNCTION('123456789')
   dbms_output.put_line(v_return);
   -- do anything else you want to do with the return value here...
END;

Comment: The query that I posted as my question works fine, just looking for PL/SQL equivalent of that.

Comment: try the above as well

Comment: The above is to call the package from a plsql block

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
DECLARE
lv <COLLECTION_NAME>;
BEGIN
lv:= OWNER.PACKAGE.get_exam('123456789');
dbms_output.put_line(lv.COUNT);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a nested table type. You simply need to declare a variable of that type, and assign to it as you would if it were a scalar:

```
declare
    l_coll your_collection_type;
begin
    l_coll := OWNER.PACKAGE.get_exam('123456789');
end;
/
```

In this example `your_collection_type` is a placeholder for whatever object your function actually returns.

---

> " I am getting this error: PLS-00201: identifier 'ab_assign_v1' must be declared "

`ab_assign_v1` is the type used by your function. From the code posted in your revised question it seems that type is in the same schema which owns the package with the function. However your original pseudo-code prefixes the call with the schema name. So, putting two and two together, you need to revise the variable declaration to include the schema too. (You may need to grant EXECUTE on it too, if you haven't done this already).

```
declare
    l_coll OWNER.ab_assign_v1;
begin
    l_coll := OWNER.PACKAGE.get_exam('123456789');
end;
/
```

Comment: It returns: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: What I have posted here is basically pseudo-code, because you have not posted the real thing. Your task is to apply my suggestion to your actual code. That error means you have made a bish of it but I cannot tell you what the mistake is because I cannot see what you're running. If you can't debug your own code you will need to post a **complete, reproducible test case**.

Comment: Hi @APC, I have added the function that I am trying to call in my question. I replaced `your_collection_type` with the return type of my function and I am getting this error: **PLS-00201: identifier 'ab_assign_v1' must be declared**

Comment: You still haven't posted  a complete, reproducible test case. So I have made another guess.